# Auto increment a value when calling a function

Tags: php

How can I auto increment a value when calling a function? Here what I'm trying to do, and I need it just this way. Cant increment it any other way except when calling the function.

```
function makeyogurt($type = 1) {
    echo "Quantity $type.\n";
    makeyogurt($type++);
}

makeyogurt();
```

Comment: This is going to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that code?

Comment: `$type++` will increment the variable, but return its original value.  `$type` value is a local variable, so it will only exist inside that function call.  Did you want something like `makeyogurt($type+1);`?

Comment: You're going to want a terminating condition check before the recursive function call.  Stacks have a finite amount of space.

Comment: This will loop forever.

Comment: This is only for this question. And yes, it does loop forever and and ends with an out of memory message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$type++` is a so called post-increment, meaning it will be incremented after the value has been passed.

What you're looking for is `++$type`, which is a pre-increment and will pass the newly incremented value.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I did just this and it works. Instead of makeyogurt($type++) I did ++type. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Norman if this resolved your issue, then please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I will (and did). But I was wondering if somethings incorrect since it was downvoted.

Comment: hehe, that's funny :) I didn't down-voted this, but wouldn't have expected that this is the solution to the problem because the code in question is an infinite loop.. Now it's `-1 accepted`. I'm still unsure what the wanted to achieve here..

Answer (score 9):

The code you've shown will necessarily lead to an infinite loop. I guess you are searching for the `static` keyword:

```
function fun() {
    static $counter = 0;
    $counter++;

    echo "$counter";
}
```

If you use `static` inside a function/method definition, the variable will get created only the first time the function/method is called. It's value will be saved after the call and the variable will get initialized to that value in the next call.

Now you can call the function like this:

```
fun();
fun();
fun();
```

Output will be:

```
1
2
3
```

Check this [manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: It's not very clear from the question, but I *think* this is what the OP is looking for. +1

Comment: @AmalMurali Hey Amal! Thx :) I could explaining how to increment using pass-by-reference otherwise. While this is theoretically possible, how would make it sense?

Comment: It doesn't - which is why I [asked for clarification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336558/auto-increment-a-value-when-calling-a-function/21336628?noredirect=1#comment32165423_21336558) in the comments under the question :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Ahh, got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function makeyogurt($type = 1) {
    echo "Quantity $type.\n";
    $type += 1;
    makeyogurt($type);
}

makeyogurt();
```

Comment: hey, it has the same problem: recursivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't define `$type` outside the function it always will be 1. I'm not exactly sure what you want, but maybe this?

```
$type=1;

function makeyogurt($type = 1) {
   echo "Quantity $type.\n";
   global $type;
   ++$type;
   }    

makeyogurt(); //makes it 2
```

or this:

```
$type=1;
function makeyogurt($a = 1) {
   echo "Quantity $a.\n";
   ++$a;
   return $a;
   }    

$type=makeyogurt($type); //makes it 2
```